# mySQL/PHP query not restricting by date

Tags: php, mysql

My mySQL table has a column `date_added` which uses type TIMESTAMP. In the table, the timestamps looks like this `2017-06-17 20:08:58` when I use a visual editor.

In my PHP, I'm trying to only get the rows that have a `date_added` since one week ago. So, I'm doing something like this:

```
$weekago = strtotime("-1 week");
$sql = "SELECT * from myTable where date_added >= $weekago";
```

`$weekago` returns an epoch time like: 1498748730

If I do a straight mySQL query like this:

select * from `myTable` where date_added > 1498748730

In either case, I just get all rows returned (and yes, some of the rows have a date_added from more than one week ago).

Is the issue that the timestamp formats aren't matching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date_added >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Your current  attempt is comparing epoch time in seconds against a date column.  This doesn't make any sense.  As @HuyTrịnh correctly suggested, you could wrap the `date_added` in `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` to convert it to seconds since epoch.  But this approach in pure MySQL is not so nice:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 7*24*60*60
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$weekago = strtotime("-1 week");
$sql = "SELECT * from myTable where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) >= $weekago";
```

This will convert date_added to timestamp so 2 parameter will have the same format